# Where do I find this assets folder of Android App in React Native for Appcenter installation

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-app-center

In the documentation, it's saying that I need to copy this appcenter-config.json to the assets folder. Where do I find this folder?

> Create a new file with the new `appcenter-config.json` with the
>   following content. Don't forget to add this file to the **assets** folder
>   of your Android app.

I cannot find this assets folder in my react native app.

Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/react-native#312-integrate-react-native-android) to the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder name with assets inside

/android/app/src/main/

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find `assets` folder in following directory, just create a new one

> project_folder\android\app\src\main\

Answer (score 0):

you have both option first check same directory second u can create custom asset directory

```
 android/app/src/main/
```